# Using LinkedIn as my only point of contact on a publicly posted resume

Tags: resume, linkedin

I'm posting my resume on job boards. I took my address and phone number off of it, and I'd rather not leave my email on because I don't want to deal with spam. Is it okay if the only contact information on my resume is a LinkedIn URL?

Comment: Does the job board provide a way for interested parties to contact you through a message system?

Comment: Since I don't have a Linkdin account, that would put your application straight in the bin

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about talking that info off the version you'd post to this "job board" but leaving it on the version you send in job applications or to people who ask you for your resume?

Comment: FWIW, I get spam from LinkedIn also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are interested in people contacting you to potentially hire you, then this is a bad idea.

You are explicitly limiting the numbers of people who will or can contact you, and for those who will still contact you, you are making the process more difficult for them so you are putting yourself at a disadvantage right from the beginning.

While I use LinkedIn and other social media for background checks, I always want a phone number and a direct email address. Otherwise, well, I have to find some ways to cull the numbers down and this is an easy one:

> If you are more difficult, then your CV goes in the bin.

Answer (score 2):

As a person who has done plenty of hiring in the past several years, I can resolutely say that unless you stand out head and shoulders above the rest of the candidates in my pile of applications, any speed bump you put in my way to further the hiring process will simply get you either outright rejected or dumped to the bottom of the "consider" pile (depending on the quality of the other candidates at that time).

I may not have LinkedIn (unlikely).

I may not have a corporate LinkedIn account (very likely) and I don't want to contact you using my personal account.

I may simply not want to use something other than Email or a phone call.

Limiting yourself to just contact via LinkedIn in this scenario is a very negative thing.

If you are worried about spam et al, then create yourself a temporary email address and use that - if you own your own domain, then simply use something you can black hole later on.  Same goes for phone numbers - there are plenty of companies which will rent you a temporary number, and when your search is over you simply drop the number.  Both of these options have their own negative repercussions (what if a hiring manager digs your CV out 18 months down the road and wants to talk to you?)

Personally, I have had the same email address since 2004 and the same phone number since 2005 - I have had my CV and contact details up on various job sites a few times, and I haven't been deluged in spam mail or calls.  I do get a lot of recruiters call or email, but thats what those contact details are for!

Comment: OP is talking about a resume to be posted to job boards, not the version he'll use to *apply to a job*.

Comment: @Lilienthal but its the same issue - you really think that as a hiring manager I've only considered the CVs of people who have voluntarily submitted their CV to me?  Nope - last two hires I made were from people I found on job sites myself or other people passed to me (we dont deal with recruiters).  If I had to jump through hoops to contact them, then the CVs are tossed (unless they are a stand out candidate, then some leeway is given).

Comment: I'd say that's on you then. Either you go the extra mile as a hiring manager to go through job board and that includes the minor inconvenience of going through LinkedIn or you stick to advertising a position. The number of people who go through job boards but would still refuse to use LinkedIn seems minor at best.

Comment: @Lilienthal You are assuming that *I* am the one that goes through the job board...  And seriously, when you are one amongst 100 mediocre candidates, why should I "go the extra mile"?  As I already said, if you don't stand out in the pile, then the negatives of dealing with you reduce your chances.  Its not the matter of "using LinkedIn" or not, its the extra involvement required to contact the candidate that is the off putter - I certainly don't want to have to use my private LinkedIn account to conduct business, and the number of companies which fund paid LinkedIn accounts isn't great.

Comment: LinkedIn accounts cross the "used to conduct business" barrier by design. But the broader issue is that job boards are largely bad at generating leads and come with caveats (like having a set of contact details in public view). Your comments are correct but your answer refers to applications, not profiles on a job board, hence my original comment. Both in your answer and in the comments you seem to alternately be talking about applications or about candidates *you* are looking for. In the latter case, yes, you need to go the extra mile to talk to someone if that's their preference.

Comment: @Lilienthal Again, no my comments do not solely refer to applications.  Why do I have to repeat myself?!  Once again, actual experience of hiring seems to not count for anything here...  The problem of contact is exactly the same in both cases - unless you are a stand out candidate, the difficulty in contacting you means you risk your CV being passed over.  Oh, I wouldn't conduct business for my employer from my personal email, so why would I do it from my personal LinkedIn account?

Comment: I'll rephrase. This question is about someone leaving off contact details when posting a CV publicly. As you say, that risks you being passed over. As you also admit, you'd still jump through that hoop if the candidate was promising and you've got a vital position to fill. That basically means that doing this is a tradeoff and OP should decide if it's worth losing the small number of people who would contact him via email that wouldn't contact him via LinkedIn. When it comes to *applications*, OP would just use a regular CV, which invalidates your reference to a "pile of applications".

Comment: That's what prompted my original comment. As for your other point, you're ignoring the fact that there *is* no such thing as personal and business LinkedIn accounts. You have *one* account that you use for business contacts. If you balk at the use of a personal networking profile at work then that's your choice but that's simply how these accounts are used in the real world. And again, I'm not arguing with your experience or even your conclusiions here, I'm having trouble with the way you've worded this.

Comment: @Lilienthal I currently have access to three LinkedIn accounts, personal, corporate company and corporate me (both paid for by the company) - just because you are happy being a mouth piece for your company on your personal account, doesnt mean everyone is. The company doesnt get to use my personal accounts for anything - that account is for my use only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45012/discussion-between-lilienthal-and-moo).

Answer (score 1):

Job boards where you merely upload a resume and fill-in a form aren't a particularly effective way to get leads so I don't think you will notice any difference regardless of what you put in the contact-info header. Moreover, job-websites usually require email-based registration-- so how many job websites are we even talking about here?

That said, you will get more and higher-quality hits from a good LinkedIn profile than you will from "shot-gunning" your resume to websites.

The best way to get leads is to use all your networks (real and online) to reach out to specific people. If you do that, you'll be communicating with them in a way that they can get back to you easily, and this will require *real* contact info like email/phone.

Comment: Actually I have found that Job Boards are just a way to get spammed and cold called.  I get that from LinkedIn some too, but the leads there seem to be better and they can't call me based on my profile there.  And I will admit, my best job to date, came from a LinkedIn contact.  I also have gotten some very high profile offers from there too.

Answer (score 1):

What effect will not putting your contact details on the board itself is very specific to the place where you put these ads (country/region/campus) and other factors. Some employers may think that's cool while others will skip your ad.

If you want to avoid revealing your primary email I suggest creating an alias specific to for this job hunt or even create a new email account.